# Character: “Kei” For “To Go” (去) In Sichuanese

Tags: characters, topolect

[怎么在四川说话居然还会听不懂了](http://tieba.baidu.com/p/1976840339)

> 宜宾话和很多四川其他地方的话有代沟的，比如去字，宜宾读kei成都以南大多读ji以北读qi网上读qie

> 广安人表示也都kei

> 呵呵，就是，克耍。有些字眼他们真的不懂了

[宜宾方言](http://www.mala.cn/thread-37062-1-1.html)

> 出克：外出

- **克** seems to be the substitute character for `kei` but is there a REAL character for this word?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "REAL" character? Do you mean the etymologically correct character for the `kei` pronunciation? While I don't know Sichuanese, I wouldn't be surprised if 去 was the etymologically correct character for this pronunciation, especially since 去 historically was pronounced with a `/kʰ/` initial.

Comment: @Claw 克 is obviously just a "stand-in" character, so yes my question is what is the etymologically correct character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Claw says, 去 *is* the historical character for it. This could come from 文白异读, that is, literary/colloquial readings. That would make sense, because colloquial readings are often either more innovative, or are a throwback.

Another option would be borrowing it from another variety, e.g. Cantonese *keoi*.

Comment: The Cantonese pronunciation is actually *heoi*, not *keoi*. A lot of words that historically had the `/kʰ/` initial ended up having an `/h/`initial in Cantonese.

Comment: @Claw Just curious: was there a pattern to which remained `kʰ` and which became `h`?

Comment: @StumpyJoePete I mentioned other examples in my answer here: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/10764/166 However, I hadn't looked further into the pattern of which ones remained `/kʰ/`. At a cursory glance it seems like most of them became `/h/` (or eventually `/f/` in the case of `/kʰu/`), though there are a few that didn't. Many words that have the `/kʰ/` initial in Cantonese currently actually evolved from other initials, such as `/g/`.